# How do I configure dual monitors on a Lenovo Thinkpad T430s?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I just got dual monitors set up on my Lenovo laptop. How can I have one instance of Safari running in one monitor and another app open in the second monitor?

Comment: That is the basic purpose for using dual monitors.  Can you describe how you have configured the settings, how the monitors are connected (one is the internal display?), what result you are getting, and what you have tried so far that didn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your monitors are mirrored\duplicated. You'll need to set it to Extend mode.

- Right-click on your desktop and click `Screen Resolution`
- Click the arrow on the dropdown by **Multiple Displays** and pick the **Extend these displays.**

[image]
*Screenshot is from Windows 8.1, although it should be very similar to Windows 7.*